# Android Connectivity to PC

Tags: c#, android

I have a `C#` application on PC which regularly backs up data to a server.

I am now starting the development of an android app which I am hoping to display the same data as held on the PC and server. Having never done any android development before, I am investigating what is possible with android.

Would it be possible to send data to/from an android device directly to an application running on a PC, or would this need to go via a server?

Also, is it possible for an android app to send/receive data without the app being open? For example, the facebook app seems give me notifications even if it is closed.

Comment: The PC application could be your "server" for this, and as long as you're connected to the same subnet (like in a small office, or home), you could play with broadcasting over sockets to set up the protocol.  Is this "sync" expected to work across the internet, or intended to be used when at the PC?

Answer (score 1):

For doing work while your app being open (not interacting with the user), take a look at the [Service class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

If you are already familiar with C#, you may consider [dot42](https://www.dot42.com/download.aspx) by the way. It is a C# compiler for Android, no runtime required. Alternatively, you may look at [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) (requires the Mono runtime).

Disclosure: I work for dot42

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive notification even the app is close. Use Google Cloud Messaging push notification. This link will help you.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

And if you want to receive/send data from web. You need a web service and try to use Ksoap to connect the web service to your Android app. See this link to gather information

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but from my understanding, it's possible. Have a look at the Google Android USB connectivity reference material [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html). That should give you an idea of the concepts involved.